# How to use file protocol to access a directory on local system?

Tags: linux, file, url, file-uri

like `/usr/local`?

I tried `file:///usr/local` but failed

```
[root@www2 robot]# cd file:///usr/local
-bash: cd: file:///usr/local: No such file or directory
```

Comment: How are you trying to access these files? What language, what program,...?

Comment: What browser? Works for me on FF3.

Comment: @Zifre,only browser available?

Comment: I am using winSCP to access a remote server and also using putty to access bash shell. There is a folder named "student" and there are student profiles in that folder in word(docx) format. The path is "/data/student/studentprofile/johncallack.docx". How can i access that folder using the above path via bash shell?

Answer (score 7):

If you have a requirement to be able to access generic URLs from your shell, try using curl as a replacement for your cat:

```
curl file:///path/to/file.txt
curl http://www.domain.com/file.txt
```

But as other posters have pointed out, the shell itself doesn't understand URLs.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to deal with file:///usr/local on the command line, you could just remove the "file://" part. And do then a normal your command, e.g.:

```
echo "file:///usr/local/" |  sed 's/file:\/\///' | cd
```

Answer (score 0):

`file:///` doesn't work on `bash` or derivative shells.

It will work in most browsers, and possible `wget` and `curl`, but `bash` is not a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

bash and cd does not function across multiple protocols to my knowledge. If you want to access stuff through other protocols you have to mount them to the local filesystem.

You're not trying to cd to some location provided by a user on some web form are you?

Answer (score -1):

The `file:` protocol only exists in web browsers. Try it in Firefox, it should work. To do it in a shell, just use

```
cd /usr/local/
```

Don't use `file:`. It's the same reason why you can't

```
cat http://www.google.com
```

Which would be awesome (but you have to use something like `wget` or `curl`).

Comment: If your talking about FireFox, then yes, I know, I slipped, shame on me. It's fixed now though.

Comment: Not necessarily wget, but rather curl (i.e. "cat url").

Comment: "the file: protocol only exists in web browers"? Not so. The URL for a file is not something that is limited to web browsers.  For example, as an argument to the collection() XPath function to get a group of XML docs from the local disk.