# Can I use cURL to write to a file locally without using fopen in PHP?

Tags: php

A web hosting service I'm trying to use does not allow PHP fopen. Can i write text to a file locally using cURL but without using fopen?

Comment: The host allows cURL but not `fopen`? Have you tried using [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)?

Comment: Oh, don't I feel a bit silly not considering file_put_contents. It turns out the host does allow this if the files are local. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

cUrl does support the `FILE` protocol:

> ```
> FILE
>  - URL support
>  - "uploads"
>  - resume
> ```

[Source](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/features.html)

If your host disabled `fopen` but did not disable that protocol with curl, you might have found something that qualifies as a workaround for you.

Example FILE URL:

```
file:///path/to/file.txt
```

See as well: [How to use file protocol to access a directory on local system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947228/how-to-use-file-protocol-to-access-a-directory-on-local-system).